# QT проблема соединения с базой данных

Tags: qt

Решил я винду поменять и скинул на флешку 2 файла minGW и файл с проектом. После переустановки поставил qt и залил эти два файла как обычно все стояло. Все запустилось и работает, но начались проблемы с соединение бд (до этого все было норм и работало).

Ошибки:

QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.

В коде есть проверка на запуск бд она не срабатывает значт бд он видит и проблема не в расположениях файла (как я думал по началу).

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("database_link1.db");
db.open();
if(!db.open())
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "OOPS", "База данных не открыта!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы дважды БД открываете, о чем варнинги и говорят.

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("database_link1.db");
//db.open(); - это не нужно
if(!db.open())
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "OOPS", "База данных не открыта!");
}
```